# Argument must be an object that implements Database.Batchable

Tags: unit-test, batch, salesforce-id

I have wrote a batch class and now i am writing test class for it but i am getting this error. Argument must be an object that implements Database.Batchable

Batch class

```
global class CBatchCalculateRatingsHistoricalData 
{
// Persistent variables
global Boolean hasErrors {get; private set;}

// Constructor
global CBatchCalculateRatingsHistoricalData()
{  
    this.hasErrors = false;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
  system.debug('Processing start method'); 
    // Query string for batch Apex
    String query = ''; 
    query += 'SELECT Id,name,Date_of_First_Order__c,Number_of_Orders__c FROM Account ';
    if(system.Test.isRunningTest())
        query += ' LIMIT 200';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> objectBatch)
{

}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}
}
```

test class

```
@isTest(seeAllData = true)
public class scheduledBatchable
{  
 static testMethod void Test_CBatchRatingsHistory()
  {
      System.Test.startTest();
     CBatchCalculateRatingsHistoricalData b = new CBatchCalculateRatingsHistoricalData();
     Database.executeBatch(b, 200);
     System.Test.stopTest();

 }

 }
```

please tell me what is the issue with this code. If i am wrong then please help me to get it right.

Answer (score 4):

Your class has to implement the interface, so that the platform can cast it to Database.Batchable and pass it to the Database.executeBatch method (which requires a parameter of this type).

```
global class CBatchCalculateRatingsHistoricalData implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
```

**Note:** Also you no longer need to make the class and its methods global, unless you want to expose the class to code outside your package.

This is a really useful [topic](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) in the developers guide, it also covers best practices on testing Batch Apex.